# Different visualisation in attribute table

Tags: qgis, attribute-table, visualisation

[image]

The visualisation in the attribute table is different for fields with the same data type (some are greyed out and the values have different positions)

Any suggestions?

Comment: Do you have a join on your layer ?

Answer (score 3):

You can right click on the layer to open its properties and go to the Attribute Form tab.

`editable` will enable/disable (and grey out) the field.
Type `range` will let you "scroll" through numerical values and will right-align the number.
Type `Text edit` will let your type a value and left-align it.

[image]